# How to know if a function is continuous, difference between elementary and non elementary functions?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity

So i am facing a problem with defining continuity. So far, I have understood that to find if a non elementary function (one that is given in parts) is continuous at a point, I need to compare the left and right side limit as that function approaches that point. For example:

[image]

For checking at zero, I can find the left side limit as x approaches 0-, and right side limit as x approaches 0+. Then if they are the same, I can define the function at f(0) since 0 is included in the domain with 0<=x.

My questions are the following:

For this same example, if 0 wasn't included in the domain, can I even check the continuity at that point or is it not continuous just because x isn't included in the domain?

Adding to my previous question, If a function was elementary, or a sum of elementary functions, for example:

[image]

So the domain of this function is [image: (-infinity,1) U (1, infinity)]. So how do I check if this function is continuous at point 1? I have learned that elementary functions are continuous on all of their domain, but if I needed to prove it instead of just writing that, would I also be able to find the right and left side limit or no?

Comment: What is your definition of continuity?

Comment: @localshop Well I can say that a function is continuous on an interval if it doesn't have any jumps or breaks, we can draw it without lifting our hand off the paper. (English is not my first language, hope I explained it well).

Comment: Don't you know a *mathematical* definition of continuity?

Comment: Let's say $g= f$ on $(-\infty,1)\cup (1,\infty)$  and $g(1)=c$ we can say that in this case $g$ is never continuous in $1$ however if $\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=c$ then $g$ would be continuous. So sometimes it makes sense to informally talk about continuity in points where function isn't defined, because you can extend the function to be continuous in those points.

Comment: @kingW3 so by my understanding, if the function is not defined at 1, but we find the right side and left side limit to be equal, then we can extend the definition of the function, meaning that we write that our function at 1 is defined by the value of the limits we got, f(1) = c. But for the first example in my original post, since the function is defined at x=0, we have to find the right and left limit, and if we get the same value, we still also check if f(0)=c ?

Comment: @kingW3 meaning that the main difference is that when the function is not defined at a point, we can define it additionally, and if it is, then we have to check if that value of the function at that point corresponds to our limit values at that same point?

Answer (score 0):

A function can only be continuous at a point where it exists, so it is never continuous on a point that is not in its domain.

Comment: I disagree - the question is asking whether you can test continuity at a point outside the function's domain, and this answers that question directly.